# Is there a way to quickly switch Themes?

Tags: theme

I have my normal modelling theme:

[image]

And then I change to a 3D no-gradient white background with grid scale = 0 and no relationship lines in perspective mode:

[image]

I then use this to take screenshots of the object for further processing in Paint.

Is there a way to quickly store and switch between these two Theme layouts? I find this a bit quicker than adding a camera, white background and rendering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Only Rendered and Wold Background to achieve the same result.
[image: Settings]

Comment: Yep, sounds more efficient and flexible than theme switching